# Which item goes up while inserting in a full node in a B-tree of order 5 and why?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, b-tree

I'm trying to learn designing a btree.
Here are the values to develop a btree of order 5.

1,12,8,2,25,6,14,28,17,7,52,16,48,68,3,26,29,53,55,45,67.

When I insert 25, it breaks into child nodes

```
         8
      /     \
    1 2    12 25
```

may I I know on what basis 8 comes up as parent ? Why not any other number ? What if the order of btree would be 4 ?

Comment: What kind of help are you looking for? Is it a generic question about btrees, or do you think that the code you wrote is not working as expected?

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini, not its not about code.I'm trying to understand how indexes work in back-end so that I could reap their benefits more in tuning sql queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a B-tree of order 5 each node (except the root) must have 2 to 4 values in it.

At the point you enter 25, the node has the values 1,2,8,12. In order to have at least 2 values in each new child (1,2) and (12,25) you have to split at 8.

Comment: Why 8, others numbers like 2 and 12 is there as well ? that's my question. is there anything am missing to understand how and what point number get split according to b tree order ?

Comment: @roy: because 8 is the only edge that can keep the btree balanced

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini, May I know how many leaf nodes branch nodes can have ?

Comment: Each intermediate node has 1 more children than values. So there may be 3 to 5 children.

Answer (score 0):

Before inserting `25`, the node state is like this:

Full node: `1, 2, 8, 12`. Items in node are always sorted in B-tree.

When you insert the new item `25`, the sequence becomes: `1, 2, 8, 12, 25`.

In this sequence the middle item is the one that is promoted up.
A node split divides the data items equally: Half go to the newly created node,
and half remain in the old one and the middle one goes up. This is the reason why `8` goes upward.

The following figures contain a B-tree of order 5 and should help understand this situation better although the data inserted is different. In the sequence on right-side, the arrow indicates the item to be promoted upward.

[image]
[image]